# Command line oneliner to find out last IP address assigned by Internet Connection Sharing

Tags: windows-10, connection-sharing, ics

I am using Internet Connection Sharing in Windows 10 for connecting a second computer, and I'm noticing that the IP address the second computer gets is not always the same.

Is there a command line oneliner that I can run on the Windows 10 computer that performs ICS, to find out the last assigned IP address to the second computer?

For now I have to walk to another room and find it out by getting physical access to the second computer, this is highly inconvenient.

Edit: Difference with similar question about Windows XP is the different OS version.

Comment: @doenoe problem is the same but windows xp is pretty old compared to windows 10 and I thought it's worth asking since windows 10 does certain things differently

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have too many devices on this local network of yours, you can use a tool for windows called the advanced ip scanner.

When run, it displays all the devices on your lan network. 
 https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/

So run it, find your device on it, and hence also get it's IP address

Comment: Oh wait, I'm sorry, I did not see the command line one liner written in the question.

Comment: a CLI oneliner is what I'm looking for, otherwise I could just enable logging for Windows Firewall and look for DHCP related info at the bottom of it. I hoped that ICS has its own log somewhere, where it records the IP addresses it assigns to clients.